# How to write into a MP4 container with Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, mp4

I need to export an MP4 file containing several streams of audio. There is no video at all at this point in time, though this might be requested sometimes in the future.

All this is on the Mac running a decently recent version of Mac OS X. QT Kit is not an option. Portability to iOS would be a bonus.

Where should I look? A very casual look at AV Foundation suggests this might be a way, but doesn't look simple at all.

Or should I rather look for a third party library? ffmpeg? mp4v2?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: AVFoundation is the way to go, it works on both iOS and OS X. There is lots of smoke code floating around the Internet.